# Creating XML from SQL Table (Unique XML formatting)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, for-xml-path

So, I'm trying to create a XML file from a SQL table. I do know of the route of using...

```
Select * From dbo.[db_name]
FOR XML PATH
```

But the issue at hand is that the XML styling/formatting is quite odd...

```
                    <ID>170607A13</ID>
                    <MaterialActual>
                        <MaterialLotID>170607A13</MaterialLotID>
                        <MaterialActualProperty>
                            <ID>CreationDate</ID>
                            <Value>
<ValueString>2017-06-07T12:26:27.667-05:00</ValueString>
                            </Value>
                        </MaterialActualProperty>
```

Therefore, I decided I could go the route of concatenating it and inserting into the XML file. Like so...

```
DECLARE @NAME varchar(50)
DECLARE @LOCATION varchar(50)
DECLARE @SearchXML xml

SET @SearchXML = '<Root>
            <CallerInformation>
                <LastName>' + @LOCATION + '</LastName>
                <FirstName>' + @NAME + '</FirstName>

            </CallerInformation>
        </Root>'

SELECT @SearchXML
```

But when doing this I get returned...

[image]

If I could get pointed in the right direction or even a example that would be great!

Comment: Learn the xQuery functions and don't do string concatenations in XML. This may be a good starting place for you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107827/how-to-update-insert-inject-nodes-into-xml and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the issue at hand is that the XML styling/formatting is quite odd...

What is odd there? The only thing odd I can see is the attempt to solve this on string level...

Your question is missing sample data and expected output. The simple `select` you provide tells us nothing, the XML you provide is an inclompete fragment and the actual example is something completely different...

Just some hints:

- **Do not concatenate XML on string level!**
- please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)
- and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Your simple example should be done like this:

```
DECLARE @NAME varchar(50)
DECLARE @LOCATION varchar(50)
DECLARE @SearchXML xml

SET @SearchXML = 
(
    SELECT @LOCATION AS LastName
          ,@NAME AS FirstName
    FOR XML PATH('CallerInformation'),ROOT('Root'),TYPE

);

SELECT @SearchXML;
```

This will lead to an almost empty (**but valid!**) XML, put any value into the variables and you will see the XML filled.

### UPDATE: Your *odd* XML...

Try something like this:

```
SET @xml=
(
    SELECT '170607A13' AS ID
          ,'170607A13' AS [MaterialActual/MaterialLot]
          ,'CreationDate' AS [MaterialActual/MaterialActualProperty/ID]
          ,GETDATE() AS [MaterialActual/MaterialActualProperty/Value/ValueString]
    FOR XML PATH('')
);
SELECT @xml
```

### UPDATE 2: Very long XPath...

This is your error: name-length more then 128

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
--SET @xml=
--(
--    SELECT '170607A13' AS ID
--          ,'170607A13' AS [MaterialActual1234567890/MaterialLot1234567890]
--          ,'CreationDate' AS [MaterialActual1234567890/SomeMore1234567890/EvenMore1234567890/StillMore1234567890/MaterialActualProperty1234567890/ID1234567890]
--          ,GETDATE() AS [MaterialActual1234567890/SomeMore1234567890/EvenMore1234567890/StillMore1234567890/MaterialActualProperty1234567890/ValueString1234567890]
--    FOR XML PATH('')
--);
--SELECT @xml
```

--This is a solution: nested sub-select:

```
SET @xml=
(
    SELECT '170607A13' AS ID
          ,'170607A13' AS [MaterialActual1234567890/MaterialLot1234567890]
          ,(
          SELECT
          'CreationDate' AS [EvenMore1234567890/StillMore1234567890/MaterialActualProperty1234567890/ID1234567890]
          ,GETDATE() AS [EvenMore1234567890/StillMore1234567890/MaterialActualProperty1234567890/ValueString1234567890]
          FOR XML PATH('SomeMore1234567890'),TYPE
          ) AS [MaterialActual1234567890]
    FOR XML PATH('')
);
SELECT @xml;
```

### UPDATE 3: Your follow-up question in comment

*HINT*: Avoid follow-up questions. Next time please add a new question!

Both return the result requested:

```
SELECT 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX' AS [PublishedDate/@format]
      ,GETDATE() AS PublishedDate
FOR XML PATH('')

SELECT 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX' AS [@format]
      ,GETDATE() AS [*]
FOR XML PATH('PublishedDate');
```

In my eyes there's no need for the format. Within XML a `datetime` should be in this format (which is ISO8601) anyway. This is the standard format...

Comment: Now that I'm using this route, I'm having a issue where I am using more than 128 Characters `,GETDATE() AS [SyncProductionPerformance/ProductionPerformance/ProductionResponse/SegmentResponse/MaterialActual/MaterialActualProperty/Value/ValueString]`

Anywhere you can point me?

Comment: I've been struggling to replicate the following xml... `<PublishedDate format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX">2017-06-22T13:04:55.574-05:00</PublishedDate>` Any help on this?